# Why do I keep getting String out of Range?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

```
return nameString.substring(nameString.indexOf(" ", 0), nameString.lastIndexOf(" ", 0));
```

Why is it keep returning an error? I just want to return the string from the first occurring space character, to the last occurring space in the string?

Comment: Can you confirm that the string has two spaces?

Answer (score 4):

> #### [lastIndexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
>
> ```
> public int lastIndexOf(String str,
>                        int fromIndex)
> ```
>
> Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index... If no such value exists, then -1 is returned.

Get rid of the `, 0` parameters to indexOf and lastIndexOf. When you pass a fromIndex of 0 to lastIndexOf it searches *backwards* from the start of the string to find a match. When it doesn't find one it returns -1 which is an invalid argument to substring.

```
return nameString.substring(nameString.indexOf(" "), nameString.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: Okay! Duh, I should have thought of it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's break your question in parts

```
String nameString = "Your name is Matt";
```

***indexOf :*** *it start reading from left to right & stop when first matched char found, and returns the position of char*

```
 nameString.indexOf("M", 0) /* returns 13 */
 nameString.indexOf(" ", 0) /* returns 4 (it's placed at 4'th position in the given sentence) */
```

***lastIndexOf :*** *it start reading from right to left and stop when char matched and returns the position of matched char*

```
nameString.lastIndexOf("t", 17)  /* returns 16 */
nameString.lastIndexOf(" ", 17)  /* returns 12 */
nameString.lastIndexOf(" ", 0)  /* returns -1,
```

*Caution : you are making mistake to giving the position 0, it reads from right to left and found nothing matched so returns -1)*  */